# What is the C# equivalant of Java's SettableFuture and ListenableFuture?

Tags: java, c#, .net, guava, porting

I'm porting Java code that uses the concurrent Guava library to C#. I came across many uses of `SettableFuture` and `ListenableFuture`.

Is there a C# class that comes very close to this pattern? Or do there exist C# wrappers for it? Because I want to change the flow of the code as less as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SettableFuture appears to be analogous to a [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Task already has [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321274%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which should give you the functionality of ListenableFuture.